# How can C# call a ml64 dll directly without an intermediate C++ layer?

Tags: c#, assembly, dll, pinvoke

Is there a simple way to create a Visual Studios solution having two projects - the first a ml64 assembly program that creates a .dll - and a second C# program that invokes a method in the .dll?

For example:

ml64 code  file div.asm:

```
      .code
; ulong Divide (ref ulong rem, ulong dividend_low, ulong divisor)
; sets rem to (rem*2^64 + dividend_low) mod divisor
; return floor((rem*2^64 + dividend_low) / divisor)
; assume &rem in rcx, dividend_low in rdx, divisor in r8
Divide  proc
     mov    rax,rdx
     mov    rdx,qword ptr [rcx]
     cmp       rdx,r8
     jae       ovfl
     div    r8
     mov    qword ptr [rcx],rdx
ovfl:
     ret
Divide  endp
     end
```

C# code  file main.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     // DLL support

class HelloWorld
{
    [DllImport("div.dll")]
    public static extern ulong Divide (ref ulong rem, ulong dividend_low,
                                       ulong divisor);

    static void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("This is C# program");
        long quot, rem = 3, dividend_low = 1, divisor = 20;
        Console.WriteLine("divide (3 * 2^64 + 1) by 20");
        quot = Divide(ref rem, dividend_low, divisor);
        Console.WriteLine("quotient = {0}, remainder = {1}", quot, rem);
    }
}
```

I would like to do this without recourse to an intermediate layer in C++ if possible.
What settings need be set in VS?  Does the C# code need to use PInvoke?  If so how?

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what does it do? Are you sure your assembly follows [the `StdCall` calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention)? (I don't know enough assembly to verify that.)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, you just create a DLL in whatever unmanaged language you like (assembler in your case) and then use P/Invoke from the C# side to call it, there is no wrapper needed to do such a thing, as C# can call directly into unmanaged code.

Two things to watch out for. On the DLL side, make sure you export your function entry point so that external callers can use it (not sure here how MASM handles this, possibly you must put some entry indicating that, but not sure really). Another thing on the C# side is that the project must be forced into compiling for x64 (AnyCPU or x86 aren't valid here), because you're calling unmanaged x64 code explicitly.

Other than that, `[DllImport]` is the way to go.

Comment: I did need to place /EXPORT Divide in the command line explicitly in order for the LINK command to give me what I think is a proper DLL. (At least dumpbin recognizes the dll and shows Divide as an entry point.)  The C# code is definitely a x64 platform program.  However when I try to add the Div.dll as a reference I get the message "A reference to 'C:\CSharp\Troy5\x64\Debug\Div.dll' could not be added.  Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."  Do I need some sort of manifest (whatever that is)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe a little late, but there is no need to add a references from the C# side. Those references are only intended for calling other managed assemblies or for importing COM components as the message says, but for normal C-style exports unmanaged libraries, the `[DllImport]` thing contains all the info needed for the call. The DLL is actually loaded at runtime, so no hard reference to it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It works!  Here are the details for those interested:

Assembly ml64:

```
        .code
; ulong Divide (ref ulong rem, ulong dividend_low, ulong divisor)
; on entry rem is dividend_high
; sets rem to (dividend_high*2^64 + dividend_low) mod divisor
; return floor((dividend_high*2^64 + dividend_low) / divisor)
; assume &rem in rcx, dividend_low in rdx, divisor in r8
Divide  proc
    mov    rax,rdx
    mov    rdx,qword ptr [rcx]
    cmp    rdx,r8
    jae    ovfl     ; overflow if divisor <= dividend_high (includes divide by 0)
    div    r8       ; dividend_high >= 0  &&  divisor > dividend_high  =>  divisor > 0
    mov    qword ptr [rcx],rdx
ovfl:
    ret         ; ((ß-2)*ß + (ß-1))/(ß-1) = ((ß-1)*ß - 1)/(ß-1) = ß - 1/(ß-1) < ß
Divide  endp
    end
```

Managed C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     // DLL support

namespace Troy5
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\CSharp\Troy5\x64\Debug\Div.dll")]
        public static extern ulong Divide (ref ulong rem, ulong dividend_low,
                                       ulong divisor);

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is C# program");
            ulong quot, rem = 3, dividend_low = 1, divisor = 20;
            Console.WriteLine("divide (3 * 2^64 + 1) by 20");
            quot = Divide(ref rem, dividend_low, divisor);
            Console.WriteLine("quotient = {0}, remainder = {1}", quot, rem);
        }
    }
}
```

The trick was to explicitly place '/EXPORT Divide' in the link command of the assembler and to NOT try to include the dll in the References of the C# program.  Instead I just put the full path of the dll in the program.  The rest of the settings can be inferred from the following command lines:

```
ml64.exe /c /nologo /Sa /Sg /Zi /Fo"C:\CSharp\Troy5\x64\Debug\div.obj"
    /Fl"C:\CSharp\Troy5\Div\div.lst" /W3 /errorReport:none  /Ta

LINK /OUT:"C:\CSharp\Troy5\x64\Debug\Div.dll" /NOLOGO /DLL /DEBUG 
    /PDB:"c:\CSharp\Troy5\Div\x64\Debug\Div.pdb" /MAP":c:\CSharp\Troy5\Div\div.map"
    /MAPINFO:EXPORTS /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /NOENTRY /MACHINE:X64
```

Be sure to set up the build dependencies properly.

Thanks to Svick and Alejandro for their help!

Comment: How do you ensure that your parameters are passed in the registers rcx, rdx, and r8 ???

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty Visual C++ DLL project and insert your `.asm` file, and compile it. Then use `DllImport` to call the exported method from your C# project.